# navigate in gridlayout using index without up/down keypress

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-gridlayout

how can i navigate in gridlayout using index.like view pager if we have 5 pages, setcurrentpage(3) will directly jump from one page to another.like this in gridlayout i have a 4*9 items. currently highlighted item is 5, if i want to move directly to 20th item from 5th, how can i do this without using up/down keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you know the child index do getChildAt(index).requestFocus();
- If you have tag for the view do findViewWithTag(tag).requestFocus();